# Is something like this possible using just MySql?

Tags: mysql

I have this query that I'm having trouble with.

```
SELECT 
    f.*
FROM 
    siv_forms f
WHERE 
    f.urlname = 'test_form_custom_url' 
    AND f.active = 1 
    AND find_in_set(50, f.siteIds)
    AND f.endDate > 1404307448
    IF (f.max_responses > 0) THEN
        AND (SELECT COUNT(fr.id) as count FROM siv_forms_responses fr WHERE formId = f.id) > f.max_responses
    END IF
```

Basically I only want the last AND condition to be included if `f.max_responses` is bigger than 0.

I could do this with a few separate queries and PHP but I'm trying to reduce the amount of queries I have to do.

Comment: I can't really add desired results as I don't have any real data at the moment, but I'm trying to get the query to do (IF max_responses above 0, only return the form if the number of responses is below max_responses)

Comment: Come on. Get creative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case) expression should do the trick. I'm not able to test this at the moment but in its simplest form:

```
SELECT 
  f.*
FROM 
  siv_forms f
WHERE 
      f.urlname = 'test_form_custom_url' 
  AND f.active = 1 
  AND find_in_set(50, f.siteIds)
  AND f.endDate > 1404307448
  AND (SELECT COUNT(fr.id) as count
       FROM siv_forms_responses fr
       WHERE formId = f.id) > CASE
                                WHEN f.max_responses > 0 THEN f.max_responses
                                ELSE -1
                              END CASE
```

You have to be a bit creative in the `ELSE` part. I used `-1` here but I'm not sure what you want to happen when `f.max_responses <= 0`. What you essentially do here is say: `x` must be larger than `y` if `y > 0`, else `x` must be larger than `-1`.

Maybe you can wrap the entire condition in the `CASE` statement. Not sure if that will work (since I can't test it at the moment):

```
  AND CASE
        WHEN f.max_responses > 0 THEN
          (SELECT COUNT(fr.id) as count
           FROM siv_forms_responses fr
           WHERE formId = f.id) > f.max_responses
        ELSE TRUE
      END CASE
```

Comment: Thanks :), I'll give that a try. I did come up with `AND (((SELECT COUNT(fr.id) as count FROM siv_forms_responses fr WHERE formId = f.id) > f.max_responses) || f.max_responses = 0)` but I've not properly tested that to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of thinking...
You could include the data from siv_forms_responses anyway and just don't use or delete the records in php when needed.

Or because you have one or more relations between these tables, create a VIEW and make a SELECT statement on that VIEW.

That way the SQL statements remain simpler (clearer) and perhaps you php code too.